# How can I stay logged into website even though server requires interaction

Tags: browser

The web application in question is HP service manager. The server requires input every couple of minutes the thing is if I'm helping a customer remotely sometimes my session is logged out or worst logs me out and I loose my notes. Is there any Firefox extension or trick someone knows that I can use to stay logged in?

Comment: If you were sitting there just trying to (manually) keep yourself from being idle in the server's eyes (and getting logged off), how would you do it?  Have you discussed possibly increasing the timeout length with the person responsible for hosting the server?

Comment: this issue is purely server-side, and the technique required to keep your session alive depends on the application framework and the server settings. most likely the server expects a post every so often or the session is considered idle, and closed to free up the resources for other users. Its not a good idea to keep a web session going for too long, so the server will aggressively disconnect sessions that appear idle.

Comment: What about [ReloadEvery](http://reloadevery.mozdev.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frank Thomas you are correct. This issue is a server-side issue. So I tried to use [imacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/), a FF plugin that lets you record macros for the web. At first it didn't work 100% because the web app was randomly generating the ID= of the button I wanted to press. But I was able to use x and y to press the button when needed and it works like a charm.

```
VERSION BUILD=8601111
TAB T=1
CLICK X=413 Y=75
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Caffeine](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/)
It simulates key presses at random intervals, so it depends on how the website detects idleness and it might just work. Just be certain to disable while actively using your machine as the random keystrokes will interfere with you work